# Grails + WS Client throw an CXF exception

Tags: java, web-services, grails, grails-controller

I'm new in grails, and trying to build a backend for my webservice, the apps only access the webservice provided not access to databases directly.

```
package backend

import org.grails.plugins.wsclient.service.WebService

class BackendController {

    WebService webService

    def index = { 
        def wsdlUrl = "http://localhost8080/BackendService/Backend?wsdl"
        def proxy = webService.getClient(wsdlUrl)

        def result = proxy.getAll()
        render(text:result);
    }
}
```

and throw this error

```
Error 500: Executing action [index] of controller [backend.BackendController] caused exception: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied.
```

How to fix that error ?

Comment: Not an expert here, but seems like the general approach would be to look at the policy section of the wsdl and track down what's not being satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

missing the colon? before the 8080